# Amplifier with low frequency question?

Tags: transistors, amplifier

We have a problem in which an amplifier of low frequencies like in the figure is presented. The transistor has these `h` parameters:

$$h_{ie}=1.1k\Omega, h_{fe}=50 $$

In the input we have \$V_s\$ as a variable and

$$R_s = 10 k\Omega$$

We are asked to find \$A_1, A_{is}, A_v, A_{vs}, R_i, R_i', R_0\$ and \$R_0\$.

I made the pi-model also in the figure. Is it correct?

[image: The amplifier and its pi-model]

Can you please help me find what is being asked?

Below is what I think the calculations are:

$$V_0 = i_0 R_c = -g_m v_{pi} R_c$$

$$V_i = ib (Rb || rpi) = V_{pi} \frac{R_b}{R_b + r_{pi}}$$

$$A_v = \frac{V_0}{V_i}$$

$$A_{vs} = \frac{R_i}{R_i + R_s} A_v$$

Comment: Hfe is not measured in ohms, it is unitless.

Answer (score 1):

For AC signal analysis, there are mainly two steps in order to obtain the the h-parameter model

**Step 1:** Short all power dc power sources and coupling capacitors.

**Step 2:** Replace BJT with its h-parameter model.

Following step1, we have to ground the `Vcc` power source (here, there is no coupling capacitors). Resulting circuit is shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkU5fk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now we need to replace BJT with h-parameter model. So resulting figure is given below..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWOtzZ.png)</sup>

**Note:** `Rb` resistor is in between collector and base terminals. In your model, one of its terminal is connecting to ground and it is wrong. `hoe` is the `outptut transconductance` and it is also present in h-parameter model(we can avoid it in some cases, since COLLECTOR RESISTANCE is almost equal to `Rc`)

Now you need to use **`miller's theorem`**, to remove the resistance `Rb` From the current position. Presence of `Rb` make it difficult to analyse the circuit. In order to apply millers theorem, we need a voltage gain circuit. But unfortunately we have a current gain circuit. We can convert a `current gain source` to `voltage  gain source` as follows

\$i_b=\cfrac{V_b}{h_{ie}}\$

Hence, \${h_{fe}}{{i_b}}={h_{fe}}{\cfrac{V_b}{h_{ie}}}=(\cfrac{h_{fe}}{hie}).Vb=0.0454V_b\$

Now apply millers theorem,we will result the following circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5DVs7.png)</sup>

**Analysis**

**Note:** since value of `hoe` is not given, we can neglect it from small signal equivalent circuit

According to `millers theorem`,

Effect of resistor Rb at input terminal is

\$R_{bi}=\cfrac{R_b}{(1-A)}; A = 0.0454;\$voltage gain of circuit

\$R_{bi}=\cfrac{R_b}{(1-0.045)} =1.048R_b=209.6k\Omega\$

Similarly,Effect of resistor Rb at input terminal is

\$R_{bo}=\cfrac{{A}{R_b}}{(1-A)}; A = 0.0454\$

\$R_{bo}=\cfrac{{0.0454}{R_b}}{(1-0.045)} ={0.048}{R_b} =9.6k\Omega\$

**Impedance at transmitter terminal**

\$Z_b=h_{ie}=1.1k\Omega\$

**Circuit input impedance**

\$Z_i=R_{bi} || h_{ie} = 1.094k\Omega       (approx. hie)\$

**Circuit output impedance**

\$Z_o=R_{bo} || R_c = 4.9k\Omega      (approx. half of Rc)\$

**Voltage gain**

\$A_v=\cfrac{V_o}{V_i}=\cfrac{({-}{i_c}{R_c})}{({i_b}{h_{ie}})}\$

\$A_v=\cfrac{({-}{h_{fe}}{i_b}.\cfrac{R_{bo}}{(R_{bo}+R_c)}).R_c}{i_b.h_{ie}}\$

\$A_v=\cfrac{{-}{h_{fe}}{R_{bo}}{R_c}}{({h_{ie}}(R_{bo}+R_c))}=-222.634\$

**Current gain**

\$A_i=\cfrac{i_c}{i_i}=\cfrac{{({h_{fe}}{i_b}{\cfrac{(R_{bo}}{(R_{bo}+R_{c})}}))}}{\cfrac{{i_b}{h_{ie}}}{Z_i}}=\cfrac{{h_{fe}}{R_{bo}}{Z_i}}{{h_{ie}}{(R_{bo}+R_c)}}=24.36\$